# how to take one attribute value from A to B table after updating B table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I got two tables: `paper` and `paperselection`.

In my code, I want to put any paper which has `rank` attribute higher than 4 from the `paper` table into the `paperselection` table

After that, what I want to do is to take the primary key(`papNo`) from that `paper` to the `paperselection` after inserting a value into the `paperselection` table.

I got two triggers here

```
---first trigger---
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER paperselection_tr
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF Rank ON paper
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF :NEW.rank > 4
   THEN insert into paperselection (Papno, journalno, title, pdate)
values (:old.papno, :new.journalno, :new.title, :new.pdate);
END IF;
END;

---second trigger----
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER paperselection_tr2
  After insert or update ON paperselection
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update paperselection
set paperselection.papno = paper.papno
where paper.title = paperselection.title;
end;
```

I could not put `:old.papno` as `:new.papno` because of my design of the table.

but It keeps giving my error:

> ```
> LINE/COL  ERROR
> --------- -------------------------------------------------------------
> 2/1       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> 4/7       PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "PAPER"."TITLE": invalid identifier
> Errors: check compiler log
> ```

Comment: Your trigger `paperselection_tr` inserts `papno` into `paperselection` table so what is the point of your second trigger `paperselection_tr2`?

Comment: Hmmm, okay is so the problem you trying to solve that `:old.papno` is null when you'r inserting a record into `paper`? If so you need to explain this: *"I could not put `:old.papno` as `:new.papno` because of my design of the table"*. What is it about the design of your table???

Answer (score 0):

The second trigger doesn't know anything about the `paper` table, because it triggers `After insert or update ON paperselection`, and because you have no further reference to the `paper`  table  in it.

Thus it doesn't like that :

```
set paperselection.papno = paper.papno
where paper.title = paperselection.title;
```

I think that you want this

```
---second trigger----
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER paperselection_tr2
  After insert or update ON paperselection
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update paperselection
set paperselection.papno = 
   (SELECT paper.papno
    FROM paper    
    WHERE paper.title = :new.title
   );
end;
```

But this is a logical operation only if you have duplicates rows in `paperselection`.